# PHP date comparison and strtotime

Tags: php, date, datetime, strtotime

Using WIndows, XAMPP 5.6.8 I am building a simple web app in HTML and PHP.

I would like to compare a date retrieved from a database with today's date.

I have a function that successfully returns a string value (in the UK date format `d-m-y`).

My code so far is;

```
$expDate = get_api_data($id); // returns a string
var_dump($expDate); // this prints string(8) "31-12-19"
```

Using this `$expDate` value I would like to achieve something like;

```
if (strtotime('d-m-y', $expDate) > time()) { // if date > than today
    echo 'date is greater than today';
}
elseif (strtotime('d-m-y', $expDate) < time()) { // if date < than today
    echo 'date is less than today';
}
else { 
    echo 'date not found';
}
```

Currently I am receiving *date is less than today* - even though the date is `31-12-19`. I'm not sure if I am approaching this the correct way?

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I have alreday spent a lot of time researching answers to no avail.

Comment: Your `strtotime()` will give you todays date and 00:00:00 as time and `time()` will give you today's date including the time (higher value if the time is after exactly midnight), so it will always be greater... .

Comment: strtotime needs a valid format, you can't just pass in your own format. Please check out the documentation at http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Comment: Btw, strtotime doesn't take a date format as the first expression.

Comment: It looks like you might have meant to use `date_create_from_format`, but that wouldn't work with `time()`, since one returns a DateTime object and the other returns a timestamp (an integer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got this error when executing your code

> PHP Notice:  A non well formed numeric value encountered

You should look at the doc in order to make a good usage of this function: http://php.net/manual/fr/function.strtotime.php

The first param should be a time, not a format.

By the way, i prefer use DateTime class to compare dates, you can do:

```
<?php

  $expectedDate = \DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-y', get_api_data($id));
  $nowDate = new \DateTime();

  if ($expectedDate > $nowDate) { // if date > than today
    echo 'date is greater than today';
  }
  elseif ($expectedDate < $nowDate) { // if date < than today
    echo 'date is less than today';
  }
  else {
    echo 'date not found';
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$formattedDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-y', $expDate);
$expDate= $formattedDate->getTimestamp();
if ($expDate > time()) { // if date > than today
echo 'date is greater than today';
.....
```

Try above code sample, try to use DateTime class if you have PHP 5.2.0 or higher http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php . Then using that dateTime object you can do comparisons in a way you want e.g. in my sample I am doing it by time.

Your code will show a notice. if you turn on the php error reporting, you will observer it.